# dynamic menu background color change with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have menu.php.i want to include all of other file.so i have error to change menu background color& font color on click event. pls check my code give me solution.thanks.

in css file
     .add{background-color:#000; color:#fff;}

in js file

```
<script type="javascript">

    $(".clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color':'#000','color':'#fff');
    $(li:first-child).removeClass('add');
 }); 

</script>
```

in html file

```
<ul>


 <li class="clickme add"><a herf="">Home</a></li>
 <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Services</a></li>
 <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Porfile</a></li>
 <li class="clickme"><a herf="">About Us</a></li>
 <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Contact Us</a></li>



</ul>

enter code here
```

Comment: use `({'background-color':'#000','color':'#fff'})`

Comment: tip: use `.addClass` that will be more easy

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `{}` brackets in your code so your code will not even compile in jquery .you can do it as shown below :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".clickme").click(function(){
         $(this).css({'background-color':'#000','color':'#fff'});         
 }); 
});
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/21/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the brackets inside `css()` function, as Neel said.

And put a smarter mode to remove add class when found.

SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/don/j2cgttuL/2/

---

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="clickme add"><a herf="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Services</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Porfile</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    // Change background on click
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#000','color':'#fff'});

    // Remove class add     
    $('ul li').removeClass('add');
});
```

Comment: I think you can just do `$('ul li.add').removeClass('add')` to remove the class.

Comment: Yep, but the funcion removeClass will be performed even if the class doesn't exist. I don't know how is removeClass beckend execution, but i think it's desnecessary. But i'll change to code to appear easier to understand.

Comment: `$('ul li.add')` only grabs `<li>` elements that have the `add` class. So there wouldn't be any case of trying to `.removeClass('add')` from an element that didn't have that class.

Comment: Got it. I thought the removeClass() was performed on any ul li element, having or not having the class. I changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

made some tweaks

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/2q9wyheh/2/

html

```
<ul>
    <li class="clickme add"><a herf="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Services</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Porfile</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="clickme"><a herf="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul li{
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#000;
}
.add{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

jquery

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $("ul li.clickme").removeClass("add")
    $(this).addClass("add")

});
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `ul li` rule, since they'll just default to normal styles once the `add` class is removed. Also, although this probably is what the OP needs, it doesn't match the behavior of the original code after fixing syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="top" class="shadow">
  <ul class="gprc"> 
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Text1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Text4</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
<style>
.active {
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
<script>
$("#top a").click(function() {
    $('#top a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suryakiran/wfjcpsvr/